# Hide HTTP GET/POST request getting displayed in Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have an application developed in Angular JS and Webapi. I have used token based authentication using OWIN Framework. The application is deployed in a Software company and few developers who have knowledge on this techstack, use Chrome developer tool and access the api methods directly and bypass the validations in Client side. Is there a way to control this?

Please find the screen shot of chrome developer tool displaying Bearer token, Webapi method & its payload.[image]

Comment: I never use OWIN before, but the usual logic is: 
auth is unique and generated from the server with a secret, the server should check whether the token is valid based on the secret keyword. So there is no way you could hide it once other developer has access to your browser, because the token is stored (usually in your browser cookie). However, they cannot generate token freely because server will check the validity of each request based on the incoming Auth bearer string.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really hide HTTP request showing up on browsers. What you can do is control who gets hold of that access token, its expiry time and what permissions and claims he has.

**You can't hide the browser's activities from a user running that browser.**

A token should be generated only upon successful login using right credentials and that token showing up on the developer tool can be used to call the API's from tools like the postman until it's expiry(so, set a shorter expiry).

Token A generated using credential of user A should not have the permission to manipulate data of user B and this should be handled explicitly.

So, the one option is that user A can steal his own access token and use it to manipulate only his own data unless the token is alive.

Comment: use jsonp if you want to hide